Weird bug when trying to determine if a file is an image or video
I'm developing a Flutter app where I need to differentiate between image and video files. However, I've run into a peculiar issue: my client has this video file saved from WhatsApp, and when picking it in the app, it is seen as an image instead of a video.
He sent me the file via Google Drive & Slack, and the video was a .mp4 on both of them (which was working fine when I tried myself).
However on my client's iphone, when printing the path of the video it was ending with ".jpeg".
Here's my code to determinate if it's a video or an image :
// true if image
// false if video
  // Read the first 12 bytes of the file
  final List<int> headerBytes = await file.openRead(0, 12).first;
  final String? mimeType =
      lookupMimeType(file.path, headerBytes: headerBytes);
  if (mimeType == null || !mimeType.startsWith('image/')) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
} 

The extension should not matter, and a platform like Stack did see it as a video, so what am I doing wrong here?
Is my way of getting headerBytes correct?
I've tried with and without header bytes, but same result

Why are you reading the first 12 bytes instead of reading defaultMagicNumbersMaxLength bytes?  It's also not necessarily true that await file.openRead(0, n).first; will return all n bytes, although it's probably true for small values of n such as 12.  Have you tried inspecting/logging what mimeType is?

You can use the mime package.
Funtion to identify an image:
import 'package:mime/mime.dart';

bool isImage(String path) {
  final mimeType = lookupMimeType(path);

  return mimeType.startsWith('image/');
}


The OP is already using lookupMimeType, presumably from package:mime.
